# C# Populate label with multiple rows from query

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, label

I have several rows which I want to add into label in my winform. My problem is that it only shows one row. How code should be modified so all rows are presented? I only need it for the first part 'reader.HasRows', for the 'else' part it is always one row. The program checks whether external or internal ID is used.

My code is:

```
private void btnCstID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string groupId = textCstID.Text.Trim();
      string queryStringInt = ("SELECT [Data_Group],[Internal_Customer_ID] FROM [CS_RT_CUSTOMER_DETAILS] WHERE [Customer_ID] ='" + groupId + "' and [Active] = 'Y'");
      string queryStringExt = ("SELECT left([IP_ID],10) FROM [CS_RT_CUSTOMER_DETAILS] WHERE left([IP_ID],10) ='" + groupId + "' and [Active] = 'Y'");
      string connString = @"..";

      using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
      {
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand(queryStringInt, connection))
            {
                  connection.Open();
                  SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand1.ExecuteReader();

                  if (reader.HasRows)
                  {
                      while (reader.Read())
                      {
                          description2.Text = String.Format("Customer ID to use: {0} - {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));

                       }
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       using (SqlCommand sqlCommand2 = new SqlCommand(queryStringExt, connection))
                       {
                            reader.Close();
                            object reader2 = sqlCommand2.ExecuteScalar();
                            {
                                description2.Text = String.Format("Customer ID to use: {0}", reader2);
                            }
                        }
                   }
             }
      }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a List<> to store the returned rows and then concatenate/output them as you wish.
Or as this is just a simple string to be concatenated then you can use a StringBuilder like this;

```
....
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (reader.Read())
{
    sb.Append(String.Format("Customer ID to use: {0} - {1};", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1)));
}
description2.Text = sb.ToString();
....
```

Comment: `AppendLine()`, otherwise you get kind of a string meatloaf (it's assumed that `Label.AutoSize = true`).